# How do I increase console-mode resolution?

Tags: display-resolution, tty

When my computer goes to console mode (booting up, shutting down or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1)</kbd>), the text is super big. I can't take a screenshot of it, but it looks like a 640 x 480 resolution. My monitor normally works at 1440 x 900.

I remember that the console text that appeared while installing from the CD was nice and small.

How can I make the console text look like it looked while booting from the CD?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've found a solution that works from [this forum post](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=41881#p2705863)

In short:

Open `/etc/default/grub` with your favorite editor as root.

Localize the line that says `GRUB_GFXMODE= ...` and change it to the resolution you want. Add another line for a new variable called `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD` with the same resolution. It should look similar to this:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1440x900x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=1440x900x32
```

Save and exit. Then edit as root `/etc/grub.d/00_header`

Localize the line that says `if [ "x${GRUB_GFXMODE}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXMODE=...` . As before, change the resolution there to the one you want and add another line for payload:

```
if [ "x${GRUB_GFXMODE}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXMODE=1440x900x32 ; fi
if [ "x${GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=1440x900x32 ; fi
```

Finally, locate the line that says set `gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}` and add a line for payload below it. It should look like this:

```
set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
set gfxpayload=${GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD}
```

Save and exit.

Still as root, refresh grub with

```
update-grub2
```

Reboot, and both the grub menu and the console should have nicer resolutions.

Finished!

Comment: This did not seem to work for me. I was using the resolution of 1366x768x32.

Comment: My solution will only work for grub2, I think. Are you using grub 1, maybe? If yes, try with a lower resolution first - for example 1024x768x32. Regards!

Comment: unfortunately didn't work for me, running 10.10

Comment: my monitor's default resolution is 1680x1050 so I just replaced every 1440x900 with 1680x1050. No luck.

Comment: Looks like that at the moment grub2 doesn't use 'GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD' option, only 'GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX'. See the official documentation on grub2: http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#gfxpayload

Comment: It would be more interesting to see a response that is more generic, that will work with most resolutions.

Comment: Seriously, It works :)

Comment: What's the difference between GRUB_GFXMODE and GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD?

Comment: This answer is depreciated and did not work for me on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS. Furthermore, it involves editing a file named `00_header` which really should not be edited.

Comment: This solution failed to me with `1440x900x32` but it did work for `1024x768x24`. I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS in VirtualBox 4.3.26. Vranger's answer worked smoother.

Comment: this solution does not work with UBUNTU GNOME 15.04

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04, but I did not need to do the step of editing 00_header. Modifying /etc/default/grub and then running sudo update-grub and rebooting was all I needed.

Comment: There's no reason to edit `/etc/grub.d/00_header`.  See the [answer by A.B.](https://askubuntu.com/a/609523/272667)

Answer (score 23):

This helped me on Ubuntu 14.04 with ESXi 5.5 :

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Change line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash vga=792"
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot -r now
```

Use 795 or 799 for higher resolution (More details [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/vga-boot-modes-to-set-screen-resolution/)).

Comment: This solutions worked for me. The `splash` option froze the login screen and it is unnecessary in my opinion.
Btw I really don't like the cryptic options like 792!

Comment: its deprecated in 15.04

Comment: works on fedora 21 too

Comment: @JiříDoubravský then what to do? other answers dont work

Comment: `reboot` command doesn't like the `-r` option, anyway.

Comment: @JiříDoubravský  Seems you're wrong:  this just worked on my just installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS!

Comment: If after-init software startup changes the resolution, just add **nomodeset** to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

Answer (score 20):

1. Start in the GRUB menu
2. Press <kbd>C</kbd> to go to the GRUB command line
3. Run `vbeinfo` and make a decision (e.g. 1920x1200x32).
4. Start your system again
5. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
6. Change `GRUB_GFXMODE=` (e.g. `GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1200x32`)
7. Set `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX` to `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep`
8. `sudo update-grub`
9. reboot your system

Comment: among all the answers on this question, this is the one that worked for me with Ubuntu 16.04 server (and it's the simplest one)

Comment: Wrt step 2 above: I find one should press 'c' for a command-line (not 'E')

Comment: Doesn't work on VMware Workstation Player with Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: @Sebi2020 Now which one? VMware Player or VMware Workstation? Works for me on VMware Workstation 14.0 with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @0xC0000022L VMWare Workstation 10

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 and later, use `videoinfo` instead of `vbeinfo`.

Comment: Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in Virtualbox, I also needed to apply the solution in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1350886/ubuntu-server-18-04-screen-resolution-reset-on-boot) prior to the `update-grub` step.

Comment: It's pointless if you have proprietary nvidia drivers (at least in my case) - because some segments of text will be blurry.

Comment: I am on Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 20.04.3 installed. This method works for me

Answer (score 15):

### Set the graphics mode with `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX`

First, install `xrandr` and run it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xrandr
$ xrandr
```

The available screen modes are listed.

Now, edit `/etc/default/grub`:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Assuming a previously unedited file, make the following changes:

The variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` should contain at least `nomodeset`, perhaps in addition to `quiet` and `splash` on desktop systems.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

On server systems, uncomment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` to see more messages passing during boot before entering in the graphics console.

Leave this line as a comment:

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

At the end of the file, add a line:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1280x1024x16
```

or replace the value by any other (comma separated) mode(s) that is(are) supported by your hardware. The values `text`, `keep`, `auto`, `vga` and `ask` should also work.

Finally, after saving the edited `/etc/default/grub` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and exiting it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, issue the following commands:

```
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo reboot
```

This answer will also work to decrease the resolution and/or refresh rate or frame buffer frequency on down-clocked systems. CRT monitors typically show flickering stripes when the refresh frequency is too high.

Comment: there is no hwinfo anymore

Comment: @obayhan Well noted! You may use `xrandr` instead.

Comment: Works with 16.04.

Comment: THIS. This is the **only** thing that worked for me on 16.10.

Comment: blurred text :-(

Comment: @daGo Choose a resolution and colour depth that is supported by both your monitor and graphics chip!

Comment: It doesn't matter on any depth

Answer (score 5):

Why i answer this threat even if it's very old? The answer is pretty easy, because so many other threat refer to it.

If `vbeinfo` or `hwinfo --framebuffer` doesn't show the native resolution of your display, then disable vesa, to do so remove vga= options in:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Search for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` and remove `vga=` if you find it.

If you have remove the option don't forget to generate a new grub.cfg:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If you don't know you did it well, then just reboot and open a terminal:

```
grep vga /proc/cmdline
grep -ir vga /etc/modprobe.d/
```

If grep doesn't show anything, then you removed the vga= option.

Now install uvesafb:

```
sudo apt-get install v86d
```

Make sure the uvesafb module is included into your initrd.  Add it to the end of /etc/initramfs-tools/modules:

```
sudo sh -c "echo uvesafb >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules"
```

To see what modes are available:

```
sudo modprobe uvesafb
cat /sys/bus/platform/drivers/uvesafb/uvesafb.0/vbe_modes
```

Now configure uvesafb mode_option=YOURxResoultion-BitColorMode e.g. 1280x1024-32:

```
sudo sh -c "echo options uvesafb mode_option=1280x1024-32 scroll=ywrap > /etc/modprobe.d/uvesafb.conf"
```

Don't forget to rebuild your initrd:

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
```

Now you can reboot!

See [this](http://blog.samat.org/2010/11/09/High-resolution-text-console-with-uvesafb-and-Debian/) for more details.
It is for debian, but it also works for ubuntu.
I hope it helped you and it should be more generic than using grub2.

Comment: +1 no need to change the grub config and `uvesafb` works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 with a proprietary nvidia driver ([recommended in other places KMS](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33605/1321) is unsupported in this case)

Answer (score 4):

Just some personal background: in my other computer I have no problem with that fancy mode (it's 160 cols x 60 rows, but it has a 4:3 CRT monitor). It's equipped with a TNT2 (yes, I swear), and that mode was promptly displayed on first boot. Problem is, it does this by loading the ***nouveau*** driver, and this guy is still a bit faulty (in my case, it hangs the whole system when trying to move windows). So, to have an usable system, I had to downgrade to the old and stable ***nv*** driver, and also disabling mode-setting ('cause the kernel would always load nouveau when enabled). Note that I'm not using nVidia proprietary drivers, but like you, I was switched back to 80x25 in console mode.

This is because the nv driver doesn't use kernel [mode-setting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode-setting). Now, I don't know about the proprietary drivers, but I'm guessing they might have changed your configuration in order to be usable, and possibly that's why you're seeing that "big" mode. Possibly they disabled mode-setting when installed. That's why you see the "small" text mode when booting from the Live CD.

You could try booting up with a different VESA mode, but that depends a lot on your hardware. For that, please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers. For example, if you'd like to try booting your text mode on 1024x640, you'll find that the mode ID is 877.

So, when booting, hold the SHIFT key (in case you don't have a GRUB timeout) to bring up GRUB's menu. Select the mode which you wish to boot and press 'e' (to edit the commands). At the end of the "kernel" command, add `vga=877`. The number is the mode ID, if you want to try other modes, replace it with the desired number.

Also, at that same Wikipedia page, you could also try the helpful "Universal format" right below the modes table. That *hwinfo* command is quite useful.

Comment: I use grub2, not grub. I didn't know that grub was responsible for the console, so I didn't mention that in my question. Sorry. I've found a solution with grub2. Regards!

Comment: To be true, the solution you found also seem simpler. Glad you sorted it out, and thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

**Ubuntu 18 console mode**:

Edit

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quite"
```

in

```
/etc/default/grub
```

so new line looks like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet vga=XXX nomodeset"
```

where XXX comes from

https://www.pendrivelinux.com/vga-boot-modes-to-set-screen-resolution/

then reload grub config and reboot

```
update-grub2
reboot
```

Comment: It seems like this question has already a many similar answers. Perhaps you could clarify what motivated you to add your answer (i.e. what information was missing from previously posted answers).

Comment: It's just simple. And suitable for newest Ubuntu 18

Comment: `"splash quite"` is a typo for `"splash quiet"` - this worthless editor won't let me change just that without making unnecessary changes elsewhere, so maybe you need to add your reasoning in the main body of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will not change the font on boot, but for the console on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[1-6]</kbd>

Install the custom Ubuntu fonts for your console:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console
```

And create a script `/usr/local/bin/fontset` with this command:

```
#!/bin/sh
setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/Uni3-TerminusBold32x16.psf.gz
```

(choose the desired fon out of the folder `/usr/share/consolefonts/`)

You can either call `fontset` each time on your console after using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

or add this line to your `/root/.profile`

```
[ ! -t 0 ] && sleep 1 & /usr/local/bin/fontset
```

(don't add this to your users .profile or you get an error on a graphical boot)

source: [Resize font on boot message screen and console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548522/resize-font-on-boot-message-screen-and-console)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to increase the console resolution on an Ubuntu server 20.04.2 VM by editing `/etc/default/grub` and setting `GRUB_GFXMODE` to the desired resolution (in my case, setting `GRUB_GFXMODE=1152x864`), and then by running `sudo update-grub2`. I was able to find the available resolution modes by running `sudo hwinfo --framebuffer`. I'm using [grub 2.04](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiGhbaRkb3wAhWzMn0KHey5A6MQFjAAegQIAxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Flaunchpad.net%2Fubuntu%2F%2Bsource%2Fgrub2%2F2.04-1ubuntu26.11&usg=AOvVaw0zfYfZ-_HqnuMFy17H2nsS).

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on Debian Stretch 4.9.51-1.
No GUI, only console mode:

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add the following line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash vga=795 nomodeset"
```

For a list of `vga=` codes see http://pierre.baudu.in/other/grub.vga.modes.html

The `nomodeset` prevents the resolution from changing again after grub initializes [thanks [How do I increase console-mode resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18444/how-do-i-increase-console-mode-resolution#comment1449339_470804) ]

**EDIT:**
As mentioned by @Videonauth :
Afterwards do:

`sudo update-grub`

Comment: To make changes in `/etc/default/grub` is not enough, you as well need to run afterwards `sudo update-grub` to make it happen