# Screen goes blank after boot options on 15 inch monitor but it works fine on 19 inch

Tags: display-resolution, console

I have a problem with Ubuntu 14.04. server. When I plug in a 15-inch monitor, the screen shows boot options and then goes blank, but the boot process continues and I'm able to log in with ssh, the problem is just that I get no display.

Everything works fine with a 19-inch monitor!

I assumed it's a console resolution problem

I've already unsuccessfully tried all options described here: [How do I increase console-mode resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18444/how-do-i-increase-console-mode-resolution)

What else can I try?

Comment: After the boot options and when the screen goes blank, try turning off the 15 inch monitor, then turn it back on. Or, if it has multiple inputs switch to another input and then switch back. This is what works for me on one of my servers, whereas another monitor works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, just add `blacklist gma500_gfx` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf` in order to disable Linux Kernel Framebuffer for this graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be coming to resolution. The resolution for a screen 15 inches is usually 1024 * ...

On your 19-inch watching the parameters of the resolution of the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer right. Do you mean he whould reduce the resolution to 1024x768 while it is connected to the 19" screen? If this is the case please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/590359/edit) your answer and add it. As of right now it's not entirely clear what you are suggesting.

Comment: I think that the resolution does not fit the screen size.

So you should try to lower the resolution on the 19 inch and plug 15 inch. 1024 * 768 resolution is for a 4/3 screen, this might not be the ideal resolution for your monitor (16/9?), but it's for the test

Comment: It didn't help me. I've changed the resolution

Comment: It didn't help me. I've changed the resolution GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768 in /etc/default/grub and no result for 15 inch monitor, nothing changed