# How to change screen resolution in ubuntu 16.04 (VGA compatible controller: XGI Technology Inc. (eXtreme Graphics Innovation))

Tags: 16.04, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I want to change screen resolution to higher value, here is what I have try:

1-

```
$ cvt 1280 1024

# 1280x1024 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.31M4) hsync: 63.67 kHz; pclk: 109.00 MHz
    Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync

$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

$ xrandr --addmode default "1280x1024_60.00"  
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
default connected primary 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600       75.00* 
   1280x1024_60.00  59.89  

$ xrandr --output default --mode  "1280x1024_60.00"
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

2- accepted answer here: [How do I increase console-mode resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18444/how-do-i-increase-console-mode-resolution)

here is more information about system:

> $ sudo hwinfo --framebuffer

```
02: None 00.0: 11001 VESA Framebuffer                           
  [Created at bios.459]
  Unique ID: rdCR.Zgkzt5gj_l5
  Hardware Class: framebuffer
  Model: "XGI Volari Z11"
  Vendor: "XGI Technology, Inc."
  Device: "Volari Z11"
  SubVendor: "XGI"
  SubDevice: 
  Revision: "1.11.05"
  Memory Size: 32 MB
  Memory Range: 0xf4000000-0xf5ffffff (rw)
  Mode 0x0302: 800x600 (+100), 4 bits
  Mode 0x0300: 640x400 (+640), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0301: 640x480 (+640), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0303: 800x600 (+800), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0304: 1024x768 (+128), 4 bits
  Mode 0x0305: 1024x768 (+1024), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0307: 1280x1024 (+1280), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0330: 1600x1200 (+1600), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0331: 1600x1200 (+3200), 16 bits
  Mode 0x030d: 320x200 (+640), 15 bits
  Mode 0x030e: 320x200 (+640), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0310: 640x480 (+1280), 15 bits
  Mode 0x0311: 640x480 (+1280), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0313: 800x600 (+1600), 15 bits
  Mode 0x0314: 800x600 (+1600), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0316: 1024x768 (+2048), 15 bits
  Mode 0x0317: 1024x768 (+2048), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0319: 1280x1024 (+2560), 15 bits
  Mode 0x031a: 1280x1024 (+2560), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0332: 320x240 (+320), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0333: 400x300 (+400), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0334: 512x384 (+512), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0335: 320x240 (+640), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0336: 400x300 (+800), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0337: 512x384 (+1024), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0338: 320x200 (+320), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0339: 640x400 (+1280), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0312: 640x480 (+2560), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0315: 800x600 (+3200), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0318: 1024x768 (+4096), 24 bits
  Mode 0x031b: 1280x1024 (+5120), 24 bits
  Mode 0x033f: 1920x1440 (+1920), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0340: 1920x1440 (+3840), 16 bits
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

> $ sudo hwinfo --monitor

```
112: None 00.0: 10000 Monitor                                   
  [Created at fb.71]
  Unique ID: rdCR.EY_qmtb9YY0
  Hardware Class: monitor
  Model: "Generic Monitor"
  Vendor: "Generic"
  Device: "Monitor"
  Resolution: 800x600@75Hz
  Year of Manufacture: 0
  Week of Manufacture: 0
  Driver Info #0:
    Max. Resolution: 800x600
    Vert. Sync Range: 50-90 Hz
    Hor. Sync Range: 31-48 kHz
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

> $ xrandr | grep maximum

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
```

> $ sudo lshw

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Z11/Z11M
                vendor: XGI Technology Inc. (eXtreme Graphics Innovation)
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:11:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: vga_controller cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:f4000000-f7ffffff memory:fbd00000-fbd3ffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

> $ xrandr

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
default connected primary 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600       75.00* 
  1280x1024_60.00 (0x272) 109.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  63.67KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock  59.89Hz
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281509/how-do-i-change-the-screen-resolution-using-ubuntu-command-line/398740

Comment: @tso, the only output device in my case is default, I have update my question with more result.